# Would accessing an unprotected IP camera be considered illegal in most countries?

Tags: legal

**Context**: You might have heard about [Shodan](https://www.shodan.io/), the website that acts as a web search for devices accessible from the Internet: home cameras, nuclear plants, crematorium, you name it.
On it you can find an awful lot of private cameras accessible from the Internet without a proper protection.

This lack of security can go as far as:

1. No authentication whatsoever
2. Default admin:admin or admin:1234 auth through POST forms

**Question:** In both these cases, would someone visiting the camera's IP and staring at the live feed for a few minutes be on the illegal side of the law in most countries?
I know this is country-dependant and I've searched a little but have come back from my searches quite empty-handed.

I feel like the law is awfully blurry when it comes to IT, and I'm quite interested in that aspect.

Comment: Far too broad - there are 196 countries in the world, and many of them have laws which might cover this scenario. In the UK, say, it would probably fall under "unauthorised access to computer material" in the Computer Misuse Act. In the US, it might fall under the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act.

Comment: I **do** know that, really, but I wanted to have an overview on how the question is treated, even if it's through examples (like the ones you gave me!). For example, the term "unauthorised access to computer material" quite bugs me. If the device is accessible to anyone on the Internet, I'm having some troubles identifying why it is unauthorised in that case.

Comment: Well, the original CMA was written before the web took off - you were supposed to have authorisation to connect from the server owner. It didn't really handle "anyone can look at this" situations, since it wasn't an option to view content without logging in (hence explicitly _doing_ something). However, you can "just view" something 1000s of times, and cause a denial of service (and get arrested), so there is clearly a line between "acceptable" and not, even when just looking.

Comment: I can answer for the case of Sweden. Both cases are illegal.

Comment: As far as option 2 is concerned, it is illegal wherever there are laws prohibiting unauthorised access or similar computer crimes. Even if the password is very weak, the legitimate owner still put a password protection because he didn't want strangers to access the camera, so it's the same as gaining access to a password-protected website.

Comment: Regardless of the law...is there ever any *ethical* reason to view random cameras in people's homes over the Internet, without their knowledge?

Comment: Of course there is not, and who exactly said there was one?

Answer (score 2):

Guessing at a default password runs afoul of just about any jurisdiction (like the US and most other developed nations) with legal language like "Whoever—
intentionally accesses a computer without authorization or exceeds authorized access".

However, pursuant to question number one, it would be interesting to know if there have been any cases involving access of a wholly unprotected system without the intent of financial gain (which are the two points the CFAA and similar laws uses as a basis) which resulted in conviction. I don't believe there have been any in the US.

Answer (score 1):

I would err on the side of caution and say yes.

Most countries have laws prohibiting unauthorized access to a "computer system." Whether that covers "open" resources such as public-facing webcams with no authentication is a legal question that none of us could really answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

For scenario two I would say yes in most countries. If we change the context to a physical key the answer is a little less cloudy. Say you find one that gains you access to a house, institution, nuclear plant, military installation. Using said key at the very least would be breaking and entering, trespassing, or burglary. Not including what additional laws might of been broken that covered that location. The same applies to the username/password. Just because you have it, doesn't mean it gives you the legal right to access the content it provides.

For scenario one it is a bit tricky. One could say they stumbled on it or the courts might chalk up the host at fault. However that doesn't mean that will be the case. In 2010 a hacker by the name of Weev retrieved iPad user information from AT&T. The information was gained from a non protected user facing web site. He was able to use simple GET requests to gain information without any authentication. As a result he was prosecuted and sentenced to 3.5 years in prison.

Aside from the technical intrusion aspects keep in mind many countries have privacy laws. And you could be breaking those just by viewing the camera feed without the host's consent or knowledge. And instead of just the home owner or business trying to prosecute you the state or country could try to prosecute you as well.

So to answer your question. It is hard to determine and pretty broad. But the safest answer is that accessing the cameras is potentially illegal if not illegal in most countries.